# Appending a file or overwriting a file

Tags: file, overwrite

I'm working with a team to parse exported data files, and one of the questions we are trying to figure out is whether the file is appending to itself or overwriting itself. We believe the file is appending to itself, but we can't be sure.

Is there a way to find out if the file is appending to itself or overwriting?

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking. if thew files are being exported by a program, the file open lines ought to indicate whether it is overwriting or appending. if you don't have the source, i'd stop the program, create a file with the name with a line like `¤first line¤` and if that is still there after an export job, it is appending. otherwise it is overwriting